# ESP32 (Arduino IDE) OTA update hangs / fails

Tags: arduino, ota, esp32

I cannot get OTA updates to work on my ESP32 using the Arduino IDE (and I've also tried PlatformIO in VS code).

I'm using the standard sketch from [this site](https://diyprojects.io/arduinoota-esp32-wi-fi-ota-wireless-update-arduino-ide/) (and many identical others).

When I try to update using OTA, here's what I get:

```
Sending invitation to 10.0.0.245 
Authenticating...OK
12:12:49 [ERROR]: No response from device [after a short while]
```

If I connect the device to a USB/serial terminal, here's what I get:

```
Start updating sketch
Progress: 0% [never proceeds beyond 0%]
Error[2]: Connect Failed [after a short while]
Error[4]: End Failed
```

My partition table has two OTA partitions, so this is not the problem.

I've tried with and without my firewall, with and without my anti-virus, with and without the USB connected, with and without a password, with and without setting the port, with and without a manual reset after loading the sketch - always the same.

It's not an initial WiFi connection problem - the device IP is recognized as a port, the password is verified if I use one and the initial connection is made.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: you can try with OTAwebUpdater (https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ArduinoOTA/examples/OTAWebUpdater/OTAWebUpdater.ino)

Documentation:- https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/OTAWebUpdate/OTAWebUpdate.md

Comment: Thanks, but that's the one that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem although with ESP8266, it didn't work when I disabled firewall either. But, after I created a **New Rule** in "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" for the python located in: C:\Users\Erfan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1\python3.exe
and **Allowed its connection**, my problem was solved.

**Note1:** Try creating **New Rule** in your antivirus firewall if you have one.

**Note2:** I found the location of the ...\3.7.2-post1\python3.exe in Arduino IDE. If you try to upload Over The Air, the path to python.exe will appear in the outputs.

Comment: Yes. Python runs the Platformio commands. So that includes the OTA updater. It will try opening a port for that, but Firewall will (usually) prevent that.